# Do microcontrollers go through an impact/drop test?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino

I am planning to use an UP Board (https://up-board.org/) to gather some data in a rocketry project and I was wondering if micro controllers have some sort of impact rating. Meaning, would it stop working if the rocket crashes into the ground? and what would be a good way to find more information on this topic?

Comment: It will rather fall off the PCB than will stop functioning by itself.

Comment: Likely something else gets damaged than MCU. Crystals may damage under shock and vibration. Capacitors may have microphonic effects. Batteries may short and burst into flames, vapourizing the MCU in the process.  So it may not matter if a cheap MCU survives the  impact or not. The UP board also has no MCU, it's an Intel 11th Gen Core SoC.

Comment: If have seen some test reports for shock and vibration in NEC and Panasonic parts. I can not remember the standards tested against and/or the specific parts in question. But they were made for automotive.

Comment: Practical answer: the MCU dice is safely potted inside its plastic chip package, and you can almost certainly smash the whole rocket into pieces without damaging it.

If this were a safety critical application you might be forced to prove that empirically, but for what you're doing I would say "don't worry about it".

Comment: Microcontrollers [in general, and majority of the ICs] aren't tested for shock and vibe.  When shock and vibe is important, PCB assemblies or complete devices are tested.

Comment: Actually I just looked at your link, and I wouldn't call that a MCU. I'd call it a SBC (single board computer). The most likely failure for that is inertia tearing heavy parts like heatsinks and electrolytic caps off the board. The chips themselves are very impact tolerant by comparison.

Comment: Many components have “industrial” versions which are tested in harsher conditions than regular versions. It’s often just an extended temperature range, but there may be tests for vibration or shock for some. You may also search for “rugged”.

Comment: Are you asking about the **chip** (which is, properly, the microcontroller), or the **board** (which is, properly, a single-board computer).  Please _edit your question_ with this clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microcontrollers, and the boards that they are mounted on, *can* come rated for shock and vibration.

Generally, chips aren't rated for shock and vibe directly, but rather they're rated for things like how flat the board has to be, and how much it can flex during operation.  Then some mechanical engineer needs to make sure the board is thick enough and well-enough supported for those conditions to be met under the intended environmental stress.

Look at the data sheet. If it doesn't make any claims, then you can figure that the particular part you're looking at hasn't been designed or tested for it.